# Exclude source files in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode5

In Xcode 4 I was able to add a user-defined build setting (EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES) in order to exclude source files for my release builds.

How do you do this in Xcode 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the build settings editor (Click the Build Settings button at the top of the project editor). Choose Editor > Add Build Setting > Add User-Defined Build Setting. The build settings need to be visible in the project editor or else the menu items to add a user-defined build setting will be disabled.

Comment: Wildcards can also be separated by spaces, for example "*.a *.b"